# ICE Default IO error in Spyder Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, spyder

There was one post regarding this issue on SO. But there it was mentioned that deleting this file ~/.ICEauthority would help. I am not confident of doing this as I fear it may screw my Ubuntu OS.

Whenever I try to run a particular program in Spyder Ubuntu, it will start executing but at the end it throws up this error.

```
  ICE default IO error handler doing an exit(), pid = 3900, errno = 32
```

I ran the same program without any issues in Spyder Windows. I am not sure what the issue is as the program runs just fine in Windows.Could anybody please help me on this?

Comment: You could try to rename `~/.ICEauthority` just to see if removing would help.

Comment: This might be a silly question. How do I find this particular file in Ubuntu? I started using Ubuntu recently

Comment: `~/.ICEauthority` is the full path of the file; `~` refers to your home directory. You can do `mv ~/.ICEauthority ~/.ICEauthority.bak` to rename it, and the reverse to put it back.